# unbinded USB device get automatically bind on linux

Tags: usb, linux-device-driver, ftdi, lsusb

I tried to use **echo -n '2-2' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind** to unbind a USB device that connects to FTDI chip, but I found that it get auto binded right after I run the command.

My **lsusb -t** looks like:

```
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=usbfs, 5000M
    |__ Port 2: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=usbfs, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/10p, 480M
```

My **lsusb** looks like:

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0403:**** Future Technology Devices International, Ltd 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**ls /sys/bus/usb/devices** has:

```
1-0:1.0  2-0:1.0  2-2  2-2:1.0  2-2:1.1  usb1  usb2
```

After I run **sudo bash -c 'echo "2-2" > unbind'**, my **dmesg** outputs following new messages

```
[Jan15 11:03] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
[  +0.272120] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
[  +0.020880] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=0403, idProduct=***
[  +0.000006] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  +0.000003] usb 2-2: Product: FTDI **********
[  +0.000003] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: FTDI
[  +0.000002] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: 000000000001
```

You can see that USB is disconnected, but then new USB is found and get assigned a new device number. It feels like my USB device is rebinded instead of unbind. Does anyone know the reason? 
Thanks!

More information: 
I tried run **echo -n usb2 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind** to unbind bus 2, it works and dmesg shows:

```
[Jan15 12:33] usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 8
```

My **ls /sys/bus/usb/devices** changed to:

```
1-0:1.0  usb1  usb2
```

which I feel incorrect. From my understand 2-0:1.0 should alaways be there?
Then I tried to add bus2 back by **echo -n usb2 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/bind**, I got error in dmesg

```
[Jan15 12:48] usb usb2: can't set config #1, error -22
```

Comment: @vssher Thanks. I tried **echo -n 2-2 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usb/unbind** with sudo privilege but it produces same result. USB disconnects then new device is found again.

Comment: Sorry about that last post, have a look at this, please : __the contents of /sys/bus/usb/devices/ are__ 1-0:1.0 1-1:1.0 1-2:1.0 1-2:1.2 2-0:1.0 4-0:1.0 4-1:1.0 6-0:1.0 8-0:1.0 8-2:1.0 usb2 usb4 usb6 usb8 -- & --  1-1 1-2 1-2:1.1 1-2:1.3 3-0:1.0 4-1 5-0:1.0 7-0:1.0 8-2 usb1 usb3 usb5 usb7 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18765725/turning-off-a-single-usb-device-again

Comment: If it turns back on it sounds like something has a connection with it that is turning back on.

Comment: @vssher, maybe you are right. I've also added more information in my post. Can you take a look?Why can I disconnect bus2 but can't added it back? Thanks!

Comment: You might have a try at this software which helps you read what is going on with the device at a low level _LibUSB_ (Linux, Windows, MacOS) https://libusb.info/

Comment: The path to the real page (today is here: very complicated, but I'm sure you can handle this software) https://github.com/libusb

Comment: @vssher Thank you, I will give it a try!